# Change dynamically grid value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid

When I have an array like this:

```
var grid = Array([1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]);
```

And when you click(gamemap structure) on the 0 value it will be update to 1.
How do I update the whole array? So the array would be:

```
var grid = Array([1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]);
```

I thought when you click the whole array will be checked and converse the 0 into 1.
I hope I'm clear enough and someone can help me to fix this problem.

Many thanks for your time!

Fr@nk

Comment: You'll need to post more code Frank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through all 9 of your items and build your array that way.

Instead of trying to selectively update one single item in the array, update all of the at the same time.

Comment: How do I update it now I have this http://jsfiddle.net/DT2w6/. How do I update the world array everytime? Don't know how to fix this. hmmm.. var world[i][j] will not update.